# Is this form correct "afraid that " and what is the difference with "afraid of doing something and afraid to do"?

Tags: sentence-construction

I know the difference between "afraid of doing something" and  "afraid to do something" but what is the difference between these and **afraid that** . When can I use this form ?Is it used a lot ?

Comment: "Afraid that" can have a few different meanings in different contexts. Can you give us a sample sentence where you saw it?

Answer (score 1):

You may be thinking of the British (mainly English) polite 'afraid that', which is a way of prefacing a refusal or some other kind of bad news, e.g. I am afraid that I can't come to your party, I'm afraid that you have failed the examination. It does not express a genuine fear of anything, but a polite, pretended fear of upsetting the listener.

Alternatively, it can be a way of expressing apprehension about something: I am afraid that the dog may be dead, I am afraid that my father will beat me.

You should provide some examples of the usage you are asking about.

Comment: In such “polite” examples, *afraid that* means essentially “sorry to report that.” It has a close cousin in *fear*, as in, “But here I’ve been chattering away. I fear I have bored you to tears.” None of these examples involves literal fear (of danger, injury, loss, etc.), in contrast to the “I am afraid that my father will beat me” variety.

Comment: @PaulTanenbaum - that is exactly the distinction I thought I had made in my answer, isn't it?

Comment: Yes it is. My comment was intended to provide to the OP a bit of additional detail.

Comment: @PaulTanenbaum - good point.